# How do I see what my rate limits in pinterst are?

Tags: api, oauth, pinterest

We've recently started getting issues when trying to exchange the code from an OAuth redirect for a token.

It seems to be happening for every single user of our app in Pinterest so I'm thiking their API limit checks are broken somehow.

> $ curl --data
> "grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=[redacted]&client_secret=[redacted]&code=a9bcced40bd7992f"
> https://api.[redacted].com/v1/oauth/token
>
> {   "message": "You have exceeded your rate limit. Try again later.",
> "type": "api" }

I've tried using their API Explorer but the "Create token" link just redirect to the overview page for their API now.

Answer (score 0):

Running that curl with -v will show the response headers.  Looks like only five login requests per hour.

```
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 0 
< x-ratelimit-limit: 5
< x-ratelimit-refresh: 3436
```

Doing some further testing though it seems like it's **always returning 0 remaining**, even for the first request.  Perhaps a Pinterest bug?  We've contacted their support.

Comment: It seems to me too. Have you got the answer？